# Highchart-treemaps equal tiles

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts, treemap

I am trying represent JSON data in treemaps with equal squares. I found out that highchart-treemap has 4 inbuilt algorithms namely squarified, slice and dice, stripes and strip. These algorithms do not meet my requirement of getting equal tiles. Is there a way i can modify them to get the desired result? I Tried finding online for the documentation of these algorithms so that i can modify them but could not  find one.

Comment: the docs and the sources are here: http://www.highcharts.com/

Comment: i did go through it before posting this question but couldnt find anything in detail.

Comment: They won't explain their *algorithms* in the docs. Did you go through the code?

Comment: This answer may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30671929/highchart-treemap-forcing-layout-on-3-lines/30672655#30672655

Comment: @ jlbriggs : This is only for 9 data sets. My data keeps changing dynamically. I want my map to accomodate all the squares and adjust automatically. Its ok if there are blank squares in the map. And i need drill down in my map. Ex : if i click on a square, it should open a map with its children. And heat map doesnt allow me to add drill down. Correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Equal tiles will be set if you have such data. Title size is based on `value` property of each data point. Make all values equal and all tiles will have same sizes.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/f6a48zmb/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        series: [{
            type: "treemap",
            layoutAlgorithm: 'stripes',
            data: [{
                id: 'A',
                name: 'Apples',
                color: "#EC2500",
                value: 1
            }, {
                id: 'B',
                name: 'Bananas',
                color: "#ECE100",
                value: 1
            }, {
                id: 'O',
                name: 'Oranges',
                color: '#EC9800',
                value: 1
            }]
        }],
        title: {
            text: 'Fruit consumption'
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I am expecting something like a chess board. I see that, if i add more data with same value, it is represented as stripes. Is there a way i can modify it and make it look like a chess board? Its ok if i have blank tiles in the map. I just need it to look like a chess board. My data keeps changing dynamically. Also i wanted to know if i can add a custom algorithm to do so. If so, can you please provide a sample code.

Comment: @anonymous You could use 'strip' algo. and set size to a chart - http://jsfiddle.net/8wzfm0vq/ If none of [available algorithms](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.treemap.layoutAlgorithm) will fit your need, then you could [set up your own](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/treemap).

Comment: Could you please provide more inputs on setting up custom algorithm? like a sample code or something. Documentation provided on the site seems amateur

Comment: @anonymous Code sample is in Docs - look for section "Add your own algorithm". Here's a demo with a custom algorithm: http://jsfiddle.net/6gc97pqv/